# SQL Error - field could refer to more than one table

Tags: sql, compiler-errors, ms-access-2010

I cant see why im getting the error

***"The specified field qb2.WellworkOIL could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause in your SQL statement"***

Based on the query below

```
SELECT 
    qb1.CompanyName, 
    qb1.AssetName, 
    qb1.Year, 
    IIf(qb1.PrimaryProductionType='Oil', 
        qb2.WellworkOIL, 
        IIF(qb1.PrimaryProductionType='Gas', 
            qb3.WellworkGAS, 
            qb4.WellworkOilGas)) AS Selected
FROM 
    (
        (
            PEBaseQueryConditions AS qb1 
            INNER JOIN PE_Field_WellworkOIL AS qb2 
            ON (qb1.Year=qb2.Year) AND (qb1.AssetName=qb2.AssetName)
        ) 
        INNER JOIN PE_Field_WellworkGAS AS qb3 
        ON (qb1.Year=qb3.Year) AND (qb1.AssetName=qb3.AssetName)
    ) 
    INNER JOIN PE_Field_WellworkOILGAS AS qb4 
    ON (qb1.Year=qb4.Year) AND (qb1.AssetName=qb4.AssetName)
GROUP BY 
    qb1.CompanyName, 
    qb1.AssetName, 
    qb1.Year, 
    qb1.PrimaryProductionType,
    qb2.WellworkOIL, 
    qb3.WellworkGAS, 
    qb4.WellworkOilGas;
```

Comment: You need to provide different aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I think getting rid of your `GROUP BY` clause can eliminate the problem. You are not using aggregate function so group by is not required.

```
SELECT 
    qb1.CompanyName, 
    qb1.AssetName, 
    qb1.Year, 
    IIf(qb1.PrimaryProductionType='Oil', 
        qb2.WellworkOIL, 
        IIF(qb1.PrimaryProductionType='Gas', 
            qb3.WellworkGAS, 
            qb4.WellworkOilGas)) AS Selected
FROM    PEBaseQueryConditions AS qb1 
            INNER JOIN PE_Field_WellworkOIL AS qb2 
                 ON (qb1.Year=qb2.Year) AND (qb1.AssetName=qb2.AssetName)
            INNER JOIN PE_Field_WellworkGAS AS qb3 
                 ON (qb1.Year=qb3.Year) AND (qb1.AssetName=qb3.AssetName)
            INNER JOIN PE_Field_WellworkOILGAS AS qb4 
                 ON (qb1.Year=qb4.Year) AND (qb1.AssetName=qb4.AssetName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't have time to try this (apologies if this does not work) but I've not seen that alias syntax before (I don't think you need the "AS") - try this;

```
SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year, 
       IIf(qb1.PrimaryProductionType='Oil', qb2.WellworkOIL, 
             IIF(qb1.PrimaryProductionType='Gas', qb3.WellworkGAS, 
                           qb4.WellworkOilGas)) AS Selected

FROM PEBaseQueryConditions qb1 
INNER JOIN PE_Field_WellworkOIL qb2 ON (qb1.Year=qb2.Year AND qb1.AssetName=qb2.AssetName)
INNER JOIN PE_Field_WellworkGAS qb3 ON (qb1.Year=qb3.Year AND qb1.AssetName=qb3.AssetName) 
INNER JOIN PE_Field_WellworkOILGAS qb4 ON (qb1.Year=qb4.Year AND qb1.AssetName=qb4.AssetName)
```

Also, as per Jon Woo's suggestion, you don't need the "group by" if you're not using aggregate functions (e.g. COUNT, SUM...)

EDIT: You can also lose some parenthesis

Comment: I fixed the initial error which was due to having renamed the column name qb2.WellworkOIL was supposed to reference. I now get the error 'Query too complex'